# Meteor Blaze changing the DOM structure of dynamic template

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

If I have a template, as such

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div>
    <p>
      Oh Oh Oh
      <div> Hi Hi Hi </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

And I render it in another template as a dynamic template, as such

```
{{> Template.dynamic template="myTemplate"}}
```

The `div` with "Hi Hi Hi" gets moved outside of the `p` tag (I can see from Inspecting the page after it's rendered).

I think it has to do with inline elements vs. block elements or something, and block elements not being not meant to be inside inline elements. Because making the "Hi Hi Hi" div be a `span` instead makes it work just fine.

Is this known / expected behavior, or perhaps a bug? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Not sure if it's expected, but yes according to the HTML spec, you can't put a `div` inside a `p`. I assume writing valid html will fix the issue. Why not use a `span`?

Comment: Using `span` does work, and is basically what I'm doing (instead I made it not a `p` tag). I am surprised Blaze actually changes the HTML based on this, given that browsers still render such "not-allowed" things, but if the spec has the rule I guess one can't complain :)